# Wro4j LessCss Support

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, less

I'm trying to implement LESS CSS into my working webapp.
Wro4j works with default settings provided here: http://alexo.github.com/wro4j/

But adding init-params to the filter as provided here: http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/LessCssSupport does
1. Runs into exception because url is unknown (there's only uri, so I changed to uri)
2. Runs into 404 when open up localhost:8080/template/res/all.css

Here's the necessary code:

```
<!-- Wro4j Filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>WebResourceOptimizer</filter-name>
    <filter-class>ro.isdc.wro.http.WroFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>configuration</param-name>
        <param-value>DEPLOYMENT</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>managerFactoryClassName</param-name>
        <param-value>ro.isdc.wro.extensions.manager.ExtensionsConfigurableWroManagerFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>uriLocators</param-name>
        <param-value>servletContext,classpath,uri</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>preProcessors</param-name>
        <param-value>cssUrlRewriting,cssImport,bomStripper,semicolonAppender,lessCss</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>postProcessors</param-name>
        <param-value>cssVariables,cssMinJawr,jsMin</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>WebResourceOptimizer</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/res/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

wro.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<groups xmlns="http://www.isdc.ro/wro">
    <group name="all">
        <css>/resources/styles/reset.css</css>
        <css>/resources/styles/*.less</css>
        <js>/resources/scripts/*.js</js>
    </group>
</groups>
```

**UPDATE**

Debug info: http://nopaste.me/raw/11966466624ff5e201716e0.txt

Just removed `bomStripper` and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use DEBUG level logging for classes from wro4j? The 404 is shown when there is an exception and I assume the exception is caused by the LessCssProcessor which fails to process valid css code (which is not less).

The workaround is to apply LessCssProcessor only to resources having "*.less" extension. This is possible with latest versions of wro4j (the most recent is 1.4.7). Just check the examples from documentation.

Comment: It seems the wiki is outdated... `ro.isdc.wro.WroRuntimeException: Invalid strategy alias provided: <bomStripper>. Available aliases are: [...]`